# Vector Asset Studio exception parsing xml

Tags: android

I have an `svg` file (vector graphics) which opens fine in Internet Explorer, but fails when opening in `Vector Asset studio` (part of android studio) with:

For input string: **2.85465in** Exception while parsing XML file:

I think this is caused by the decimal point, where a comma is expected as the computer used has Dutch settings and **","** is expected to be the decimal separator.

Where does Vector asset studio gets it's information for this and can it be changed locally?

Answer (score 1):

With this error in Vector Asset:

```
Could not generate a preview
Exception while parsing XML file:
Premature end of file.
```

### My provisional solution was:

1. Before getting the .svg file, I generated a **.png** with Photoshop CC.
2. I converted my .png to **.svg** with a [converter](https://imagen.online-convert.com/es/convertir-a-svg)
3. [Verify](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) that my .svg can be converted to VectorDrawable. This is to know if the Android Studio Vector Asset will be able to perform the conversion.
4. And finally, I select the VectorDrawable XML that I generated when I checked and paste a resource into the drawable directory, or I use **New-> Vector Asset** to generate this resource from my verified .svg.

*With check I mean make sure the .svg will be parsed to xml with Vector Asset*.

So I observed this error occurs when the image has tiny text and when using the .svg converter is likely to skip it.

Answer (score 0):

SVG files are just text files, you can open them in any text editor (like notepad) and change their content as you like.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I tried to chanche decimale point to comma, but then there are comma seperated coordinate pairs in that file. How will that ever work out. I really think i need some way to trick or just set country code or language code to english to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

Try removeing the `in` or replace it by `px`. Asset Studio doesn't seem to work with any other *size declaration* than `px`.

There was a conversation on google groups, I think, that I recently read. Took the solution from there. Will add the link if I find it again.

// edit: found it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189654